# "...Não pode implementar um membro interface, pois não é público". .Net

Tags: c#, .net, api

Trata-se do CRUD de uma API.

Basicamente tenho 2 serviços.

Eu chamo um "validarBoleto" que está definido em "IBoletoService" para implementar um "BoletoMovimentacao".

[Chamando a funcao](https://i.stack.imgur.com/outFM.png)

[Interface do serviço](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPXZy.png)

Pois bem, se eu tiro a função [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPXZy.png) da Interface o serviço de Boleto não da erro,
já se eu o mantenho ele dá o seguinte erro:

> [Nao pode implementar um membro, nao e publico](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFBga.png).

Comment: olá, coloque o código na pergunta não imagens ou links de imagens que são difíceis de visualizar

Answer (score -2):

Em um resumo, a interface é um contrato com a assinatura dos métodos, a classe que está referenciando a interface deve implementar todos os métodos do contrato.
Logo sua classe `BoletoService` deve implementar o método `ValidarBoleto` da interface `IBoletoService`.

Para maiores informações leia a [documentação da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation)